# Cannot become ring because distribution law does not hold

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, abelian-groups, monoid

Commutative ring with unit is defined as $(R,+,\times)$, where $(R,+)$ is abelian group and $(R,\times)$ is commutative multiplicative monoid with $1$ and $+$ and $\times$ satisfies distributive law.

Could you give me an example $(R,+,\times)$ cannnot be a ring because $+$ and $\times$ does not satisfy distributive law although $(R，+)$  is abelian group and $(R,\times)$ is commutative multiplicative monoid with $1$.

Comment: `+1`, this is a great question. I was thinking about this a while back and asked this question which you might be interested in; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900991/understanding-algebras-with-alteratives-to-the-distributive-law. Your question really nails what I was trying to think about there

Comment: I thought, in ring, ＋and × are dependent(relevant) and should not be independent(irrelevant), the only conditional expression that ＋ and × appear(thus seems to relate) is distributive law. That is the background I asked this question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is a "dumb" example. Let $R=\mathbb Z$, and let $\times=+$, i.e., addition and multiplication are the same thing. Now $(R,\times)$ is a commutative monoid, with a $1$ (i.e, $0\in R$). This is clearly not distributive: $1\times(1+1)=3\neq1\times 1+1\times 1=4$.

Answer (score 11):

Let $(R,+) = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, and define $\cdot$ to be the unique commutative operation $R \times R \to R$ such that

$[0] \cdot a = [0]$ for all $a$

$[1] \cdot a = a$ for all $a$

$[2] \cdot [2] = [0]$

You can check that $(R,\cdot)$ is a commutative monoid, but the distributivity law does not hold because

$$[2] \cdot [1] + [2] \cdot [1] = [2] + [2] = [1] \neq [0] = [2] \cdot [2] = [2] \cdot ([1] + [1]).$$

Comment: This is not the smallest possible example since $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z, +, +)$ is smaller..

Comment: Oh, good point! Thank you, I'll correct my answer.

Comment: The smallest possible example with $0\neq1$ is $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z,+,+')$ where $a+'b=a+b+1$.